# C++: creating an array of local objects

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers

If I do the following:

```
string* create_array(){
    string* arr = new string[2];
    string s = "hello";
    string s2 = "world";

    arr[0] = s;
    arr[1] = s2;
    return arr;
}
```

is the assignment of `arr[0] = s` making a copy of `s` and then putting that copy in the memory address that `arr[0]` points to? or is it making arr[0] refer to the local stack variable `s`, and in this case if I use the array returned from this function calling `arr[0]` will have unpredictable behaviour?

Thanks

Comment: It is a bad practice to return an array allocated with `new` from a function. Consider using `std::vector` or `std::array` instead. You usually should not mess with raw pointers when you don't sure you need to, or, especially, if you doubt in how they work.

Comment: @Mikhail I am using arrays over vectors for speed as I am doing some real time image processing stuff.

Comment: Not really sure why the question gets a down vote :s

Comment: @Aly there is no speed difference, `std::array` should actually be faster.

Comment: @Let_Me_Be I am definitely seeing a tangible speed difference (albeit microseconds) between raw pointer and vector

Comment: Are you including the time to delete the returned array in your test?

Comment: @Aly Then there are two possibilities. 1) you are using `vector` wrong, 2) you are using some strange compiler

Comment: @Aly:  I didn't downvote, but I would guess you were downvoted because you are 1) using raw pointers to `string` objects, 2) creating a C-style array of strings, 3) copying the allocated string in to the array and, 4) leaking resources

Comment: @Al: and 5) you assume the speed difference is because of `vector`'s implementation, whereas in reality it is surely your use of it.

Comment: @JohnDibling but surely what you have just said should be put into a comment/answer as opposed to a silent downvote. This site is for asking questions to learn :S. Anyway, I am not using string* in my app, but am using cv::Mat* and have switched this for a vector<cv::Mat>* and am accessing them in the same way (random access using the [] operator) and the vector approach is slower on average 0.83 secs vs 0.74 of raw pointer. I am not an expert at C++, in fact I'm quite new to it and am struggling to explain this

Comment: @Aly:  People vote for different reasons.  There are few hard and fast rules governing how people should vote, and silent downvotes have been a part of Stack Overflow since the early days.

Comment: @Aly `cv::Mat*` and `vector<cv::Mat>*` aren't functionally equivalent. `cv::Mat*` and `vector<cv::Mat>` are. Plus it matters a lot how you actually work with the `vector`, you are most likely using it wrong since you didn't even mention how you add items into it.

Comment: @Let_Me_Be the part I'm timing is not the insertion to the vector, but the part of my algorithm where I do many accesses. I am doing them this way (using vector<cv::Mat>* vec) (*vec)[index], whereas with the cv::Mat* arr I was accessing like arr[index]

Comment: @Aly Well, that will of course be slower. You have one extra indirection. `cv::Mat*` is an array but `vector<cv::Mat>*` is a pointer to an array. Again, the equivalent of `cv::Mat*` is `vector<cv::Mat>`. And again, you haven't mentioned how you are adding items into the vector, because that will affect performance a lot.

Comment: @Let_Me_Be for addition, I am resizing the vector to the appropriate size and then inserting via vec->insert(vec->begin() + index, Mat). I see how vector<cv::Mat> is equivalent to cv::Mat*, the reason I am using a vector<cv::Mat>* is because this acts as a cache and is passed into a few objects constructors so that they can all reference the same cache without explicitly having their own copy. Is there a better way to do this? (I am quite new to cpp) Perhaps pass a vector<cv::Mat>& to the constructor and have a private reference variable in the class (I think this assignment wont copy?)

Comment: @Aly 1. If you want to insert to the end of the vector, use `push_back` instead of `insert`; 2. In your case you should pass a vector as a `const &`, that's the way to dot this in C++; 3. I downvoted because the initial question about pointers was too basic, I think it is very easy to google.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> is the assignment of arr[0] = s making a copy of s

Yes.

> and then putting that copy in the memory address that arr[0] points to?

No. `arr[0]` is a `string`, it doesn't point to anything. (internally, it probably has a `char*` somewhere, but that's unique per instance of `std::string` and is an implementation detail, I added this comment just to be complete)

> or is it making arr[0] refer to the local stack variable s, and in this case if I use the array returned from this function calling arr[0] will have unpredictable behaviour?

Nope, it makes a copy.